# AngularJS background task directive updating controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, intervals, background-task

in my AngularJS app I have to permanently check the serverside for new entries and then update the current data held in the app on client side.

So for example I have a controller `MyController` which holds an array `orders` containing `Order` objects.
When a new `Order` is made over a REST API on the serverside from another client I want to get the update in my app.
So I wrote a `directive` `orderRefresher` which is applied to the `<body>` and runs an `$interval` that fetches all orders every 120 seconds.
When the new `Orders` are fetched they are broadcasted from the `$rootScope`.

In `MyController` exists a listener which update the orders when the matching event is broadcasted.

The problem is, because the listener is set on `$scope` and gets not destroyed when the controller is destroyed what causes errors when I try to set the `orders` property (does not exists).

I thought about just wrapping it inside a `try-catch` but then I would have to wait till the `$interval` is run again to get the updates when the controller is reinstantiated.

So how can I solve this problem?
Is there a better solution then mine?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to put your HTTP logic inside a service (a singleton that exists throughout the lifetime of your application)

You can either have a controller make requests on an `$interval` or have the service do this.  Controllers could then `$watch` the resulting orders to save you having to broadcast the event.

Something like this

```
app.service(
   "orderService",
        function( $http, $interval ) {
            // Return public API.
           var api = {
                orders: []
            };

            $interval(update, 10000); //10 second interval

            return api;

            function update(){
               $http("/api/request").then(function(response){
                   api.orders = response.data;
               });
            }
        });
```

In your controllers simply inject `orderService` and then do something like

```
$scope.$watchCollection(
    function(){ 
        return orderService.orders 
    },
    function(){
        console.log("orders have changed");
    });
```